# Python wrapper to my own version of unix PS command

Tags: python, console

The class below provides a set of utility methods to access set of currently running processes. It is a wrapper around my own version of UNIX 'ps' command. Please help me improve this.

```
import os
import re

from   constants.common import EMPTY_STRING
from   util.common import execute_remote_command


class ProcessStatus(object):
    """
    This class provides a set of utility methods to access and manipulate the set of currently running processes. It is a wrapper around my own version of UNIX 'ps' command.
    """

    PS_COMMAND = "/usr/local/bin/myps --columns user,pid,ppid,tty,state,start,%cpu,%mem,command --no-header"

    #        username    pid     ppid      tty     state   starttime      %cpu          %mem       cmd
    #      /----------\/------\/------\/---------\/------\/---------\/------------\/------------\/-----\
    PS_OUTPUT_PATTERN = r'^\s*([^\s]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\w+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\d+\.?\d*)\s+(\d+\.?\d*)\s+(.*)'

    COMMAND_PATTERN = r'\s*([^\s]+)($|\s+.+$)'

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', user=None, pid=None):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.pid = pid
        self.processes = {}
        self.is_process_info_retrieved = self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        """
        This run myps command and find processes running on the given host.
        """
        user_filter = EMPTY_STRING
        pid_filter = EMPTY_STRING

        if self.user:
            user_filter = "-u {user}".format(user=self.user)

        if self.pid:
            pid_filter = "-p {pid}".format(pid=self.pid)

        actual_myps_command = "{command} {user_filter} {pid_filter}".format(command=self.PS_COMMAND,
                                                                           pid_filter=pid_filter,
                                                                           user_filter=user_filter)

        return_code, myps_output = execute_remote_command(command=actual_myps_command, host=self.host)

        if return_code:
            logging.finfo("Unable to get details of process running on host {self.host}")
            return False

        processes = myps_output.split('\n')

        for process in processes:
            if not process:
                continue

            match_return = re.match(self.PS_OUTPUT_PATTERN, process)

            if match_return:
                (uname, pid, ppid, tty, state, stime, usage, memusage, cmd) = match_return.groups()
                (command, args) = re.match(self.COMMAND_PATTERN, cmd).groups()
                command = os.path.basename(command)
                args = args.strip()

                self.processes[pid] = Process(
                    pid=pid,
                    ppid=ppid,
                    command=command,
                    user=uname,
                    arguments=args,
                    host=self.host,
                    cpu_usage=usage,
                    mem_usage=memusage,
                    start_time=stime,
                    state=state
                )

        return True

    def get(self, pid=None):
        """
        Returns a process with given pid.
        """
        if not pid:
            pid = self.pid
        return self.processes.get(pid, None)

    def generate_parent_child_map(self):
        """
        Returns a dictionary of PID as key and value as a list of its children.
        """
        parent_child_map = {}

        for process in self.processes.values():
            pid = process.pid
            ppid = process.ppid
            if pid and ppid:
                if ppid not in parent_child_map:
                    parent_child_map[ppid] = []
                parent_child_map[ppid].append(pid)

        return parent_child_map


class Process(object):
    """
    Clients should never create instances of this class but instead should get references to these objects through util.process_status.ProcessStatus.
    """
    def __init__(self, pid, ppid, user, command, arguments, host, cpu_usage, mem_usage, start_time, state):
        self.pid = pid
        self.ppid = ppid
        self.user = user
        self.command = command
        self.arguments = arguments
        self.host = host
        self.cpu_usage = cpu_usage
        self.mem_usage = mem_usage
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.state = state
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

### New Style Class Declaration

Using `class ProcessStatus(object):` is unnecessary.   You can now simply write this as `class ProcessStatus:`

### Named Tuples

Your `Process` class appears to be a class with no methods, and just holds immutable data.  You shouldn’t use a class for this.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Process = namedtuple("Process",
                     "pid ppid user command arguments host cpu_usage mem_usage start_time state")
```

Usage can be unchanged:

```
self.process[pid] = Process(pid=pid, ppid=ppid, ...)
```

### Private Members

If a user (or even you) wishes to use your module, they may `import pswrapper` and then execute `help(pswrapper)` to get details on how to use the package.  This will include being told there are members like `PS_COMMAND`, `PS_OUTPUT_PATTERN` and `COMMAND_PATTERN`, which appear to be internal details.

If you named these members with a leading underscore (eg, `_PS_COMMAND`, etc), they would not appear in the help documentation.

### Docstrings

`help(ProcessStatus.refresh)` will return the text:

> This runs myps command and finds processes running on the given host.

Um, ok.  It finds them.  And ... returns them?  As a list? Or a dictionary?  No, it caches the results, and returns `True` on success and `False` on failure.

Write docstrings to tell a programmer using this class how the function is to be used, what the arguments mean & their types should be, and when the function returns.

```
"""
Refresh the cache of processes running on the target host,
filtered by user and/or process id if configured in the constructor.

Returns:
    `True` if the process details are successfully retrieve and cached.
    `False` otherwise
"""
```

### Security

An attacker can use your script to execute an arbitrary command, using the `user` or `pid` parameters.  For instance:

```
ProcessStatus(user="root; rm -rf /;")
```

Ok, this is Python, and there is no security.  But perhaps you could raise a `ValueError` if `pid` is not an integer, or `user` contains non-alphanumeric characters.